# Why when I print it appears 80 for *str in decimal (letter P in ASCII)?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main ()
{
   char *str;

   /* Initial memory allocation */
   str = (char *) malloc(15);

   strcpy(str, "tutorialspoint");
   printf("String = %s,  Address = %u\n", str, str);

   /* Reallocating memory */
   str = (char *) realloc(str, 25);

   strcat(str, ".com");
   printf("String = %s,  Address = %u\n", str, str);

   /* Deallocate allocated memory */
   free(str);

   printf("\n%d",*str);
   return(0);

}
```

Comment: After `free(str);` dereferencing `str` is _undefined behavior_.

Comment: Accessing memory after it was free'd causes undefined behavior, anything might happen. Also, the correct way of printing pointers is with `"%p"` and `(void *)str`.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of malloc() and family in C..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Comment: `str = (char *) realloc(str, 25);` is a very dangerous pattern, should `realloc` fail.

Comment: I was just trying around code, and noticed this and since I couldn't understand why when I run the program the letter P would always come up, I decided to ask you guys. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last print says to print the character pointed to by `str` as a decimal, which is exactly what it did (for a memory location you just deallocated, making this *undefined behavior*).

Comment: It is UB and could as easily have aborted the program.

Comment: "Undefined behavior" means what happens is *undefined*; it just happened to pick the number 80 to display this time.  Next time it could be a different number, or a crash.

Comment: @Derteckpt If you are consistently getting the same value, it is could be that your standard library implementation sets free'd memory to a particular value, which happens to be 80 (0x50). If I run it, I consistently get '0'. Either way it is UB and should not be relied upon.